# Observe Ember Data store changes in component

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have a component which creates record for a specific model like this:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({

    store: Ember.inject.service(),

    addRecord(account) {
      this.get('store').createRecord('update', {
        authUid: account.get('authUid'),
        service: account.get('platform')
      });
    }
});
```

I have another component that needs to observe changes done to a particular model (i.e. if records are added or deleted), and show them in that component.

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    store: Ember.inject.service(),

    observeStoreChanges: /*What should I write so that every time `addRecord`
pushes record in the store, a function is executed in this component*/

});
```

Comment: Are these components nested? siblings? One way would be to use an event bus. http://www.thesoftwaresimpleton.com/blog/2015/04/27/event-bus/

Comment: @blessenm Yes I finally came up with a solution that used the event bus mentioned in the link you provided. However I was just wondering if there was a different  way.

Comment: Well it really depends on the components. Again nested or siblings, If its nested u use actions

Comment: @blessenm No they are not nested.

Comment: Well then event bus as a service is the way to go. If is was nested then this post will be helpful http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/how-to-communicate-to-child-components/7772/6

Answer (score 0):

If you're a fan of the observer pattern:

```
// store.js
export default DS.Store.extend(Ember.Evented, {
    createRecord() {
        const record = this._super.apply(this, arguments);
        this.trigger('recordCreated', record);
        return record;
    }
});

// component.js
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    observesStoreChanges: function(record) {

    }.on('store.recordCreated')
});
```