# Observing changes to an embedded record of an ember-data model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have an Ember component that is passed a model:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model()  {
    return this.store.findAll('source');
  },
}
```

`source` has many nested embedded records. `models/source.js` is defined as:

```
export default Model.extend({
  displayName: attr('string'),
  azureStorageName: attr('string'),
  sourceInstances: DS.hasMany('source-instance')
});
```

`models/source-instance.js`:

```
export default Model.extend({
  status: attr('number'),
  creatorId: attr('number'),
  blobName: attr('string'),
  created: attr('date'),
  conversionLogs: DS.hasMany('conversion-log')
});
```

and so on...

My controller periodically polls the backend for `source` data, and I can see this reflected in Ember Observer, with the embedded documents being updated successfully. From the component, I would like to react to changes to the embedded records of the `source` records. I have looked at the following QAs and some others and still cannot figure out a way:

[Observe Ember Data store changes in component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30253471/observe-ember-data-store-changes-in-component)

[How to observe for changes in the Ember data store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31259400/how-to-observe-for-changes-in-the-ember-data-store)

What is the simplest way to be able to observe changes to embedded records of an ember-data model? Note that these embedded records do not have endpoints on the backend.

I am using Ember 2.4.3.